# Map phase implementation in map reduce framework

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I searched a lot and i knew that in every map task when the content of buffer arrives to a threshold, a thread partitions the data according to number of reduces.what is the role of reduce numbers here? why does partitioning happen in map?how does it help map phase?after sorting , the thread will spills the content to disk.
How does it happen? i can't undersatnd the meaning of spilling here.....
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Map need to partition the data as the reducers poll and pull all the data from each mapper that is relevant to the reducer.

If you imagine it the other way around - the reducer pull all the output from each map then you'd be sending all the data output from each mapper to each reducer - hugely inefficient.

So by partitioning in the mapper, the reducer is able to query and pull back the data it needs to reduce from each mapper.